# Why are the images no wider than 500px in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Using a regular, reasonably wide Google Chrome browser, see http://abmphotography.beta.cjbm.net/aileen-kevin

The height of the images is defined in CSS, but the width should be automatic. It seems to work with the portrait images, but the landscape ones are limited to a maximum of 500px wide.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colin, you are setting the *max-width* to 100% on two selectors:

```
img
.thumbnail > img
```

This is making the image as large as the container, thus not allowing for the expansion you seek. Disabling the *max-width* properties on Chrome made the image fit the height as you would expect, as it should on other browsers too.

Comment: Thanks - that's it. For some reason I'm now not able to override it (can't edit it directly as that's coming from the Bootstrap CSS), but that's another issue.

Comment: Ah, I can't override a set value with 'auto', but I can set it to 10000% which does the job.

Comment: You can also set it to 'max-width: none !important;' if it gets in your way.

Comment: Bootsrap uses `span1`-`span12` to control thumbnail width: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails

Comment: Nathan - !important not ideal as I need to override it again elsewhere (see when you narrow the browser view).

Comment: Abraham - I don't think spanN is approriate as I'm not working with a grid here - the images are on a single horizontal ul

Comment: Just added a related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649474/google-chrome-incorrectly-displays-bootstrap-thumbnail-images-overflowing-conta

Answer (score 0):

To get the proper output as other browsers you have to remove the max-width from css, see below. I have removed the `max-width:100%;` from the below css.

```
.thumbnail > img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```