# Google Chrome incorrectly displays bootstrap .thumbnail images overflowing container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This question relates to [Why are the images no wider than 500px in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648282/why-are-the-images-no-wider-than-500px-in-chrome)

See http://abmphotography.beta.cjbm.net/aileen-kevin

This has now been fixed, but now when the page initially loads in Chrome, the wider images overflow their div.thumbnail containers. See:

[image: Example]

Weirdly, if you have the inspector open, focussed on <html> or anything within, the issue immediately corrects itself. Also if you have the console open and evaluate "$('body')" it immediately corrects (this doesn't work when in the javascript file).

Additionally, if you resize the browser above or below width:980px, then it also corrects itself (this is the point that the media queries switch, and the padding between the li's changes.

**Update:**

I have worked around this issue with the following jQuery:

```
$('ul.thumbnails img').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').width($(this).width());
});
```

However I'd welcome a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Did you try using <li class="thumbnail"> rather then <div class="thumbnail">?

Comment: Yup, that doesn't fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you're not using the row and span classes? I think I've had my divs spill outside of the window too, but immediately noticed that I wasn't using those. My structure for one row of content will generally look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`span12` can be any size you'd like. Since it's a 12 column grid, 12 would use the whole width of the grid. This may not necessarily solve your issue, then again maybe it will! Either way it's just good practice in general.

Comment: You reckon I should be using the grid, even if the design is not grid based?